# apr_socket_recv: connection reset by peer (104) nodejs Ubuntu 14.10 x64 8GB RAM 4 Core (VPS)

Tags: node.js, sockets, gps, benchmarking

I am working on a project in node.js. The project is about location(GPS) tracking. The ultimate target for my project is to server 1M concurrent requests. What i have done are,

Created a server in node.js listing on port 8000
A html document with google map to locate user positions/GPS locations
A single socket connection between server and html document to pass location information
An API to get user location from client devices ( it can be a mobile app )
Once a server receives user location via the API mentioned it will emit that information to client (HTML document) via socket.

Its working well and good.

**Problem**
I am using apachebench for load test my server. When i increase the concurrency benchmarking breaks frequently with the error

```
apr_socket_recv: Connection reset by peer (104)
```

how can i solve this, Whats the actual cause of this problem.

Note: if i run the same server in my local windows machine it serving 20K requests successfully.

I have changed the

```
ulimit -n 9999999
```

and the soft and hard file openings limit to 1000000

neither solves my problem.
please help me to understands the problem clearly. How i increase the concurrency to 1M. is it possible with some more hardware/network tunings?

**Edit:**

I am using [socketCluster](http://socketcluster.io/) on the server with the no of worker equivalent to the no of Core/CPU (i.e) 4 workers in my case
The CPU usage with the ***htop*** command in server terminal is **45%**
Memory usage was around **4GB / 8GB** & swap space not used
The **ab** command i used to load the server was

```
ab -n 20000 -c 20000 "http://IP_ADDRESS:8000/API_INFO"
```

Comment: Why down vote? is there anything wrong?

Comment: are you using node clusters? are you using the last ab? whats your response code? when it occurs whats your resources usage %? what ab command are you execuing? please provide more info

Comment: @nada. sorry for the inconvenience. I have updated the question with the information you have asked for.

Comment: try with -r like `ab -r -n 100000 -c 1000 "http://IP_ADDRESS:8000/API_INFO"` or with -k

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am not getting the error now after added `-r -k` in the command. But each benchmarking test 100-300 requests are failing. Why is that happening?

Comment: Whats the server response code from http://IP_ADDRESS:8000/API_INFO ? Check if your server receive the GETs and check if your Server response code is 100% correct